# How to set focus on datagrid when text Some text enter in Textbox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, wpfdatagrid

> I have one textbox and Datagrid.
>
> when i enter some text in textbox then my datagrid itemsource is
>   filtered and i get some value in datagrid.
>
> But now i want when i enter some text in textbox then   datagrid
>   should get focus and using Arrow key i can change selected row  along
>   with that i want that at the same time i can also enter text in
>   textbox.
>
> i m not getting what can i do?

can anyone have idea?
i m using mvvm pattern..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the keyboard focus to the DataGrid by using

```
Keyboard.Focus(myGrid);
```

Just remember tha only one control can have keyboard focus at any given time, so using this method the user can't type in the textbox while navigating the grid with arrow keys at the same time